# Can this complex SQL statement be converted to a single AR statement?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have worked out how to query what I want in bare SQL, but ActiveRecord doesn't really have a way to pass bare SQL.  I'm really struggling with how to turn this into AR friendly methods/scopes.  Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT foo.status, count(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.*
        FROM checkins t1
        WHERE t1.time = (SELECT MAX(t2.time)
                 FROM checkins t2
                 WHERE t2.host_id = t1.host_id
                 AND time <= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
                 )
    )

) as foo
GROUP BY foo.status
```

EDIT: I wanted to clarify what the data looks like.  It is a list of checkins for hosts to give their availability.  So the table has 3 columns: host_id, time, status.  The statuses are either "available" or "unavailable".  What I'm trying to do is take an arbitrary time and find the most recent checkin PRIOR to that and sum up the two status types (i.e. how many computers are available and how many are in use).

I'm not opposed to doing this the "proper" AR way, but I'm charting computer usage over time so I don't want that to turn into 40 queries to get all the information.

Also, in an ideal world this would be a scope (or similar) so that I could chain it with other constraints.  Things like Host.where(...).available_count or something like that.

Comment: What do your models look like here? Are there any associations, or is it just one model?

Comment: To work well with ActiveRecord you're going to want to find a way to write non-nested queries.

Comment: I have a host model which has_many checkins.  The checkins belong_to a host.  I also have groups which have_many hosts and a host belongs_to a group

Comment: To be clear the checkins table is a list of state-changes for various hosts.  They have entries that are Time, Host_ID, and Status.  The two statuses are "available" and "unavailable".  The table has entries for all hosts in a giant list.  What I want to do is take a section in time and find the most recent entry for each host PRIOR to that time and count the "available"s and the "unavailable"s

Answer (score 0):

If raw SQL is a valid solution for you, you can try:

```
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
```

Then

```
rows.each do |row|
  value = row["status"]
  count = row["count"]
end
```

Comment: In a perfect world I'd be able to make this a scope so that I can chain other things onto it.  For example if I put hosts into groups I could then do <group>.hosts.checkins.available_at(<time>) and get the same result just with added filtering.  But barring that, this solution might very well solve my problem.